# How to insert one thousand or more csv records into a SQL Server table using nodejs

Tags: node.js, sql-server, csv

This is my code where I'm getting `table_name` and `csv_file` from user with ejs form. Code directly extract `column_name` and `row_data` from a `.csv` file. This code is working perfectly when I upload a `.csv` file with less than 100 records, but it doesn't upload when I use more than 100 records. I even tried creating batches of 50 records at a time, but still it is not working - it doesn't throw any error.

```js
app.post('/', upload.single('csvFile'), async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // Parse the CSV file
    const results = [];
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      fs.createReadStream(req.file.path)
        .pipe(csv())
        .on('data', (data) => results.push(data))
        .on('end', () => {
          // Remove the temporary file
          fs.unlinkSync(req.file.path);
          resolve();
        })
        .on('error', (err) => {
          reject(err);
        });
    });

    // Extract the column names from the CSV file
    const columns = Object.keys(results[0]);

    // Check if the table already exists
    const tableName = req.body.tableName;
    const pool = await mssql.connect(config);
    const tableExists = await pool.request().query(`SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = '${tableName}'`);
    if (tableExists.recordset.length > 0) {
      // If the table already exists, render an error message
      res.send(`Table ${tableName} already exists.`);
      console.log(`Table ${tableName} already exists.`);
      return;
    }

    // Generate the SQL queries for creating the table and inserting the data
    const createTableQuery = `CREATE TABLE ${tableName} ( `+`Id INT IDENTITY(1,1),`+`${columns.map((column) => `${column} VARCHAR(MAX)`).join(', ')})`;
    const insertDataQuery = `INSERT INTO ${tableName} (${columns.join(', ')}) VALUES`;
    
    // Execute the create table query
    await pool.request().query(createTableQuery);

    // Batch insert the data
    const batchSize = 50;
    for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i += batchSize) {
      const batch = results.slice(i, i + batchSize);
      const batchValues = batch.map((row) => `(${columns.map((column) => `'${row[column]}'`).join(', ')})`).join(', ');
      await pool.request().query(`${insertDataQuery} ${batchValues}`);
    }

    // Close the database connection
    mssql.close();

    // Render a success message
    res.send('success');
    console.log('success');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.send('error');
  }
});
```

Here I create batches of 50 records but it's not working:

```
// Generate the SQL queries for creating the table and inserting the data

const createTableQuery = `CREATE TABLE ${tableName} ( `+`Id INT IDENTITY(1,1),`+`${columns.map((column) => `${column} VARCHAR(MAX)`).join(', ')})`;

const insertDataQuery = `INSERT INTO ${tableName} (${columns.join(', ')}) VALUES`;
    
// Execute the create table query

await pool.request().query(createTableQuery);

// Batch insert the data

const batchSize = 50;
for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i += batchSize) {
      const batch = results.slice(i, i + batchSize);
      const batchValues = batch.map((row) => `(${columns.map((column) => `'${row[column]}'`).join(', ')})`).join(', ');
      await pool.request().query(`${insertDataQuery} ${batchValues}`);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the `await pool.request().query()` inside a try-catch block?

Comment: Like on every other similar question: your code is wide open for sql injections. Imagine what happens if your CSV file contains a `'`? Don't create queries by string concatenation but use parameterized queries. "Not working" is not a proper problem description. You already have rudimentary exception handling. Is there any error logged?

Comment: @anand there is already exception handling...

Comment: So if you dump the final insert query toconsole/file/web page and load it up in SSMS, what syntax error(s) does it complain about?